# First element of the collapse menu should show and the rest should hide angular6

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have an accordion and collapse element and I am displaying using ngFor. I need the first element to show and the remaining to be hidden everytime.

I have tried modifying the ngClass attributes but it gets applied to every element in the for loop.

```
  <div id="accordion">
    <ul *ngFor="let group of records">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" attr.id="heading{{group.id}}">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" attr.data-target="#collapse{{group.id}}"
              aria-expanded="false" (click)='toggleIcon()' attr.aria-controls="collapse{{group.id}}">
              <i [ngClass]="{'fa':true,'fa-plus':icoPlus,'fa-minus':icoMinus}"></i>
              <span id='region' class='region-heading'>{{group.regionName}}</span>
            </button>  
          </h5>
        </div>

 <div attr.id="collapse{{group.id}}" [ngClass]="{'collapse':true, 'show':showEnabled}"attr.aria-labelledby="heading{{group.id}}" data-parent="#accordion"> 

          <div class="card-body " >
            <ul class='country-list' *ngFor="let country of group.countryList ">
              <li class='country-name'>
                {{country.countryName}}
                <div class='divider'></div>
              </li>
              <ul *ngFor="let campus of country.campusList" class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li>
                  <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-sm'>
                      {{campus.campusName}}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm'>
                      {{country.countryName}}, {{campus.cityName}}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm'>
                      {{campus.skypeConfNumber}}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-sm'>
                      <a [attr.href]="'tel:' + campus.skypeConfNumber + conferenceIdStr" (click)='clicked(country.countryName)'>
                        click here to join
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class='divider'></div>
                </li>   
              </ul>
             </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

the expected result is the first element should be expanded and the rest should be minimized.

Comment: `<ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"><li *[class.collapse]="i !== 0">`

Comment: I have one <ul> and the rest are put under <div>. so this doesnt seem to work. is there any other option?

Comment: That was just an example it works with divs too

Comment: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to '[class.collapse]' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. :(

Comment: That should work, but you can also use `ngClass`

Comment: it works. there is one small issue that the first card remains expanded in the first accordion click and from the second time it works fine..